# module-virtuall-surround-sink not working, does not create output in pavucontrol

Tags: pulseaudio

I am trying to use `module-virtual-surround-sink` to get virtual surround on my headset(using an hrir file). When I run `pacmd load-module module-virtual-surround-sink sink_name=vsurround` it does not work(does not create an output in pavucontrol). However when I run `pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=mySink` and open pavucontrol, a new output is created. I also tried replacing `pacmd` with `pactl` in the `module-virtual-surround-sink` command I got the following error:
`Failure: Module initialization failed`